# How can I select or alias a duckdb relation column which has an aggregate function in its column name using the Python-API?

Tags: python, sql, alias, duckdb

The DuckDB Python API lets you compose complex queries by building it up from chained functions on a relation. For example, to do a group by, one can do a simple select, and then use the aggregate function on the select relation like this:

```
rel = duckdb.sql('select date, businessunit, pnl from tbl')
rel = rel.aggregate('date, sum(pnl)')
```

This will create a new relation where all `pnl` is grouped by date and the column name for the grouped `pnl` is the string "sum(pnl)".

Now we have a problem because we can no longer select this column named "sum(pnl)" using the Python API. DuckDB can no longer differentiate between the "sum"-command on a column named "pnl" and a column called "sum(pnl)."

Referencing the column by its name gives an error because DuckDB thinks you want to sum the column.

`rel["date"]` works and gives you the date column,

`rel["sum(pnl)"]` errors with:

> BinderException: Binder Error: Referenced column "pnl" not found in FROM clause!
> Candidate bindings: "query_relation.sum(pnl)"

`rel["pnl"]` errors with Attribute error because the column is now called "sum(pnl)" not "pnl".

Aliasing the grouped columns would resolve the issue, but the Python API does not seem to give an option to do this.

Also quoting the column name does not work, because duckdb now thinks you are referencing a string and not a column:

> AttributeError: This relation does not contain a column by the name of '"sum(PnL)"'.

How can I either reference the column using the Python-api or alias the column using the Python-api?

(I could probably use pure SQL throughout, but the question is about the Python client api)